# Linksys WRT1900ACS without internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I just bought a new router, the Linksys WRT1900ACS, however, my internet is currently down.

I would like to setup my router; access point name, password etc.

Is there any way I can bypass the "Internet required" part of the setup process?

Comment: You should be able to access your router, since it has an intranet address at all times, it just wouldnt be assigned a public ip address.  If you fine the current default firmware lacking i suggest putting LEDE on it.

Comment: @Ramhound I have no trouble finding the router, nor accessing setup, however the setup requires an internet connection to proceed

Comment: As I said.  I have the same router, but I put LEDE on it awhile ago, and I am able to access it even when my internet is down.  You likely will have to do the samething.

Comment: Even if you're connected to it via ethernet you should still be able to go into your modem's config by way of 192.168.0.1 or something similar(it's listed on the bottom of your unit), there should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @tab The particular router in question seeks an internet connection back to Linksys

Comment: You seriously can't configure or use the router without an active internet connection? Hmm... I will scratch that one off my potential buy list.

Comment: Ahh yes, it's nice to come back to SO/SU after a couple years and the first thing I see is a standard Ramhound answer in which he doesn't actually understand the problem but comments anyway.  Some things never change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point you will need to first reset the router by holding in the red button on the back for at least 10 seconds while powered on.

Then connect to your router. On the first setup screen click to accept the terms then click the link for "Manual configuration" on the bottom left.

On the next screen you will get a warning that "Internet connection is down." Click the "Login" button on the bottom right of the screen.

On the next screen enter the default password of "admin" (without quotes). You will now be in the admin control panel of the router.

My guess is that you either followed the auto setup link or entered the password that comes on the device card on this screen. That's what happened to us. That password is for WiFi access only.

In conclusion, the device does not require internet access to be configured.

Comment: My router is now set up, so I have no way of verifying, if someone can verify this answer I will accept it.

Comment: I just did these steps and verified that, not only do they work but, they work wonderfully.  I just flashed LEDE and am on my brand new 5Ghz ac network!

Comment: As promised, I have accepted this answer

Comment: Bought this router in 2020. After clicking "Manual configuration" I got the 'waiting' screen for ages, got fed up and pressed F5, only then did the login page appear. Otherwise all good.

Comment: Confirmed on EA8300 that there is a "Manual Configuration" link on the bottom-left of the first screen.  However, I clicked it about 10 minutes ago and I still had a loading indicator.  I hit refresh and am presented with a page that says "Internet is down. You must have an internet connection to login to your linksys smart-wifi account".

Comment: Update, I misunderstood the screen described above. There is a "login" button on this screen. I assumed it was to try to login to the "linksys smart-wifi account" again, but it is basically a "continue to router admin" button.  In other words, the manual configuration solution does work.